# How to draw a line in LibGDX without ShapeRenderer

Tags: java, libgdx, line, pixmap

I am using LibGDX and have an ArrayList of multiple points which I want to connect. I am aware there are several methods with `ShapeRenderer` that work, however im running a SpriteBatch at the same time so what do I do now to draw a line with two Vectors. (If it exists, I'd also like the function that draws multiple lines at once with an `Àrray` or `Vector2` as a parameter, though it isn't a problem as otherwise I'd manage with a for-loop probably).

I am also aware I can use Pixmaps but they don't seem to work correctly. Here is my attempt:

```
// point1 and point2 are of type Vector2
Pixmap pixmap = new Pixmap(point2.x - point1.x, 2, Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888);
pixmap.setColor(Color.WHITE);
pixmap.drawLine(point1.x, point1.y, point2.x, point2.y);
```

In response to a possible solution that involves using `ShapeRenderer` at the same time, this problem arises (the second image uses the points with pixmaps, the first the ShapeRenderer with lines)
[image: With Shape Renderer:]

[image: With SpriteBatch and Pixmap points]

The code used for the first image is the following:

```
        for(int i = 1; i < dotPositions.size(); i++) {
            sr.line(dotPositions.get(i-1), dotPositions.get(i));
        }
```

The code used for the second image is the following:

```
        Pixmap pixmap = new Pixmap(2, 2, Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888);
        pixmap.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        pixmap.fillCircle(2, 2, 2);
        Texture texture = new Texture(pixmap);

        for(int i = 1; i < dotPositions.size(); i++) {
            batch.draw(texture, dotPositions.get(i).x, dotPositions.get(i).y);
        }
```

In both cases `dotPositions` is an `ArrayList<Vector2>` with the same values.

Comment: If you want to mix ShapeRenderer into your scene drawn with SpriteBatch, you can call `end()` on the batch, do your ShapeRenderer drawing, then call `begin()` on the batch again. You don't need to worry about this breaking up your batching unless you're doing dozens of layers this way. Trying to do this with Pixmap would be the hard way, and also terrible for graphics performance because you would have to reload the texture every time you change the lines.

Comment: perfect it works yet the lines drawn seem to be moved away from the original path. Assuming i drew all the points with the batch, they matched the path i set for them but with the shaperenderer lines they have the same pattern but moved offset to the left. I am aware that wasnt well phrased so ill add an image to the question in an edit.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone in the future may be interested, I found the solution and all I had to do was use `ShapeRender.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined)` to sync it with the SpriteBatch.